# What is inside a XML created by OpenCv Haar function.

Tags: xml, opencv, image-processing

I am using OpenCV haartraining to create a classifier for an object. http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html

  The classifier creates a XML file. I wanna know what means all those values from the XML file.

I have an idea for a start up and is all about optimizing the process of detecting an object based on multiple xml from training data. Can anyone explain me what is actually inside a XML. Lets say if i have 10 xml files from 10 training different date but with the same subject( the same car let's say) is there anything that is common between the file?

Comment: You're going to have to be MUCH more specific in your question.  Post examples and ask more specific questions.

Comment: I asked what i wanted: What is inside a XML file. and what is common between xml files. If you don't know how to answer, don't give a -1 ...

Comment: OK, what is inside "a" XML file is text that is formatted according to the rules of XML.  What is common is that they all have a single node for a root.  Does that help?

Comment: I was referring to the XML created by the haar training, i thought that i was clear with that by referring the XML file as "detecting an object based on multiple XML from training data"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options here:

- Open a XML generated by OpenCV, take a look inside and see if you can make sense of it;
- Download OpenCV source code and see how the XML is created in the code;
- Download [OpenCV Reference Manual v2.1](http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~cs4243/doc/opencv.pdf) and investigate page 470.

Comment: one more option : Learn what is haar cascade and how it is used for object detection especially face detection from a good image processing book for which google might help.